# Why was my VLQ flag on an answer declined?

Tags: support, flags

I was looking over the homepage yesterday, and found [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/202792/254353) by a new user. After looking over it, I noticed that it had content issues.

The answer was:

> Clear "phone manager" app data, it will return limit to "not set" Works on all huawei phones. It works for me

It is a somewhat acceptable answer, but seeing the answer below it changes how it looks. The answer below it (posted almost 3 months ago) is:

> Clear "phone manager" app data, it will return limit to "not set" Works on all huawei phones.

Since it sort-of had an answer in it, I chose to flag it as VLQ instead of NAA (notice how the person who wrote it **copied the other answer** and just added "It works for me").

However, my flag got declined.
[image: Declined flag]

Why was my flag declined? And can something be done about the answer for the reasons above?

Comment: The way flags are presented in the queue gives the mods no context that this may have been a copy of an existing answer. Looking at it totally in isolation it looks like a kind of poor answer, but not something that probably merits outright deletion (IMO), and so it was likely declined for that reason. If you see a case like this, where you need to consider other posts to add context, then a custom flag with more details is going to be the best option. I'll let the mod who handled it provide an answer if they'd like to, though.

Comment: Just what I wanted to recommend: if context is needed, flag it "in need of moderator intervention". That gives you an input where you can leave an explanation. I've now deleted it (with a hint to the user giving reason).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was the one who declined the flag, and eldarerathis's explanation is spot-on. I was having a clear-out of old flags - mostly, ones which we've all looked at but nobody was especially keen to delete. Without the context of the other answer, it just looks like a one-line answer that's low-quality but not **very** low quality. I suspect if this answer had been reviewed in the "low quality posts" queue, the outcome would have been the same, because you don't get to see other answers in the queue either.

As Izzy says, if the reason for the flag is not clear by looking at the post itself, it's better to use a custom "in need of moderator attention" flag. That applies to duplicate answers like this, spam flags where it's not obvious why the post is spam, and some other cases.

Another option is to add a comment to the answer before flagging it. Comments **are** visible in the flag and review queues, so if you explain the issue to the person who posted, we'll see it too. Just remember to be nice in that case, because your comment will be visible to everyone.

With an answer like this one, you could comment something like, "Are you trying to reply to so-and-so's answer by copying the text of it? Answers don't work like that on this site. If an answer works for you, vote it up so that other visitors can see it's good." Then if you flag, it's obvious to whoever handles the flag (whether a moderator or anyone in the review queue) that you think the answer is a copy, and we can check it out.